# delete and update properties of neo4j nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

this post is actually for ensuring about correctness of a cypher query. Assume you want to remove misspelled properties from all nodes and set value of those into new property, e.g like this:

```
match (u:User) set u.username = u.userrname remove u.userrname
```

As I noticed, it will check all nodes in label `User` whether it has property `userrname`, if exists it would set new property `username` with existing value and then remove the `userrname`. else, nothing would happen.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cypher you use would set `username` to `null` in case `userrname` does not exist.

So you have to limit your MATCH to the nodes where `userrname` exists

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE EXISTS(u.userrname)

SET u.username = u.userrname 
REMOVE u.userrname
```